# Find the shortest distance between a point and plane

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $A(3,2,-1), B(5,0,-2), C(3,3,0)$ and $D(5,-6,8)$ be four points in
$3$D space.Donate the plane containing $A, B,$ and $C$ by
$ABC$. Use vector methods to solve the following.

**WITHOUT** finding the equation of the plane $ABC$, calculate the shortest distance between $D$ and $ABC$.

Comment: Well, if D is (R,-6,8) answer will be in terms of R. Is that what you want?

Comment: a typographical error  R=5

Comment: [How To Ask A Homework Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/265466)

Comment: I will pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 0):

The vector product $\mathbf{n}=(A-B)\times(A-C)$ gives you a normal to the plane. So now it's just

$$\frac{|\mathbf{n}.(D-A)|}{\|\mathbf{n}\|}$$

Comment: It should be the absolute value in the numerator.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks.